# Parsing non-standard C with gtags

Tags: flycheck, c, gtags

I'm working with a codebase that's meant to be built with a proprietary C compiler using tons of esoteric language extensions. Ideally, I'd like to stick to my chosen environment as much as possible, but parsing the code for syntax/tags is hard.

The custom attributes can be handled by passing stuff like `-D __no_init=` to clang, but then we have stuff like this in the header files:

```
__saddr __no_init volatile union { unsigned char P14; __BITS8 P14_bit; } @ 0xFFF0E;
```

which makes it tough to find `P14_bit` as a tag. After some fiddling, it seems that clang actually accepts references to `P14_bit` as valid.

It seems, instead, that the gtags backend doesn't parse it "correctly". It picks up and indexes `__BITS8` and other macros/typedefs in the same file, but `P14_bit` and `P14` aren't indexed by

Does anyone have any workaround hacks to suggest?